# httpBackend explicit annotation for Angular app in strict mode

Tags: angularjs, mocking, protractor, angularjs-e2e, httpbackend

I am using Protractor's `addMockModule` functionality to mock some request data, but am having issues with the target Angular app being in strict mode.

This is the error:

```
Failed: unknown error: [$injector:strictdi] function($httpBackend) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

This is the code:

```
    var httpBackendMock = function() {
        angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['my-app', 'ngMockE2E'])
            .run(function($httpBackend){
                var expected_response = {"limit": 1}

            $httpBackend.whenGET(/homepage/).respond(function() {
                return [200, expected_response];
            });
            $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
        });
    };

    browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock);
```

Is there a way how I can explicitly inject $httpBackend in Angular's context here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly provide dependencies for your run block:

```
.run(['$httpBackend', function($httpBackend) {
    //     ^^^ - inject explicitly
}]);
```

This is basically the idea behind strict mode, that it forces you to set injection explicitly ([docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/error/$injector/strictdi)).

Alternative approach looks like:

```
angular.module('app', []).run(runBlock);

runBlock.$inject = ['$httpBackend'];

function runBlock($httpBackend) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The alternative approach worked great :)